# make row to column n insert newline in every last row

Tags: linux, text-processing, tr

i have file.txt

```
john,
5901,
open

lina,
2401,
open

jody,
5401,
open
```

I want to insert a new line every last row, The result should be :

```
john,5901,open
lina,2401,open
jody,5401,open
```

what i try

```
cat file.txt | tr -d '\n'
```

but the result like this

```
john,5901,openlina,2401,openjody,5401,open
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Awk in *paragraph mode*:

```
$ awk -vRS= -vOFS= '{$1=$1} 1' file.txt
john,5901,open
lina,2401,open
jody,5401,open
```

Unsetting the record separator with `RS=` causes awk to treat everything between empty lines as a single record, and adds newline to the default list of whitespace input field delimiters. Because your input doesn't contain other whitespace, that means each line of a block becomes a field. We then force the record to be re-evaluated by reassigning a field value to itself `$1=$1` and finally print the record with an empty output field separator `OFS=` in place of the default single space.

Comment: wow work like a charm, thanks bro .. but can u explain that code ?

Comment: @AnggoroSetiawan thanks, I have added some explanation

Answer (score 1):

```
$ paste -d '\0' - - - - <file
john,5901,open
lina,2401,open
jody,5401,open
```

This reformats the data into four columns by placing each line from the input file into the next column.  The empty line between the sections is the fourth column and it would be placed last on each output line, but since it's empty, it won't contain anything.

The data already has commas in it, so we use an empty delimiter with `paste` (with `-d '\0'`).

---

A solution using `sed` that does not assume that the data is divided into groups of three lines:

```
$ sed -n 'H; /^$/{x;s/\n//g;p;d;}; ${x;s/\n//g;p;}' file
john,5901,open
lina,2401,open
jody,5401,open
```

It does this by adding lines to the hold space with `H` and when it hits an empty line or the end of the file, it removes the embedded newlines in the hold space that `H` added, and prints the result.

Comment: this will fail if the groups were not multiply of 3

Comment: @αғsнιη Yes. But the data in the question is.

Comment: its work too, i just add - if the row > 3

Answer (score 1):

With `awk`

```
awk '{ printf (NF)?$0:RS } END{ print ""}' infile
```

This joins every lines into one if it's not an empty line (a line containing a/set of Tab, Space and Newline).

this solution is not depending on the fixed 3 lines in each group.

for an specific case if you had multiple empty lines and to avoid repeat those in result, you can do:

```
awk 'NF{ skip=0; printf $0; next} !skip{ printf RS; skip=1 } END{ print ""}' infile
```

Answer (score 1):

One way with POSIXly sed can be:

```
sed -e '
    /./!d
    $ba
    N
    /\n$/!{H;s/.*//;x;D;}
    :a;s/\n//g
' input.txt
```

**Input:**

```
% cat -ne input.txt
 1  $
 2  $
 3  john,$
 4  5901,$
 5  open$
 6  $
 7  $
 8  $
 9  lina,$
10  2401,$
11  open$
12  $
13  jody,$
14  5401,$
15  open$
```

**Output:**

```
john,5901,open
lina,2401,open
jody,5401,open
```

**Explanation:**

- Whenever `sed` sees a non-empty line (just any char, even a blank would do), it starts appending that into the pattern space and reads the next line.
- Now if the rightmost portion of the pattern space, meaning  the current line read into the pattern space is an empty line or last line, then we branch to the label `:a` wherein we promptly delete the newlines from the pattern space and print to stdout.
- And in case  the just read line is not an absolute empty, after being appended to the pattern space, `/\n$/`, we go back and append the next line.
  This we do by means of the `D` command which transfers control to the top of the `sed` code. But before that, it cleans up everything upto the first newline in  the pattern space. this we manage by placing a `\n` by `H;s/.*//;x` artifact.